# Apply same accessor to multiple attributes in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In eloquent we can cast multiple attributes to Carbon instances by specifying the dates in an array:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
```

I have multiple attributes that I want to apply the same presentation logic to and instead of using multiple accessors (one method per attribute), I was wondering if it were possible to set up an array like the aforementioned dates array by which a particular method can be applied to.

So instead of having multiple accessors, like this:

```
public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    return ucfirst($value);
}

public function getLastNameAttribute($value)
{
    return ucfirst($value);
}
```

I could instead have an array like this:

```
protected $ucfirst = ['first_name', 'last_name'];
```

and then the `ucfirst()` function would be applied to the array by creating a method to do this.

Didn't see this in the docs and couldn't find anything from a search, but I may have been searching for the wrong thing.

Any solutions solely using eloquent would be great, I don't really want to pull in another package to do it if I can avoid it. Thanks!

**Edit**

Going to investigate how the `$dates` to Carbon works and try a similar approach, perhaps this is a starting point:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2895

Answer (score 0):

I don't know such possibility.

But you can encapsulate repeating functionality to some method and use this method in your accessors.